# how to calculate exact hours from two timestamp in php?

Tags: php

I need to get the difference of hours from between two timestamps. Can you tell me how can it be done using php?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hours = (abs(strtotime($timestamp1)-strtotime($timestamp2)) / 60) / 60;
```

Comment: That will get you the difference in seconds, not hours.

Comment: @Michael Allow me to correct your correction.  It was difference in minutes, now it is difference in hours

Answer (score 1):

You can feed the values of timestamps into strtotime(), this will get you the UNIX TIME STAMP in seconds since 1970. It'll be two large integer second values. So then do a subtraction between the two values and convert that into whatever you're looking to get. e.g.

minutes, hours, days, weeks, etc... by  doing normal *60, *60, *24, *7 computation

Answer (score 0):

Use `strtotime` to convert the timestamps into seconds, subtract them, use `abs` to get the absolute value (no negative numbers here!), divide by 3600 seconds (1 hour), and then `round` to the precision you'd like.

```
$difference = round(abs(strtotime($stamp_one) - strtotime($stamp_two)) / 3600, 2);
```

Comment: If we are being nitpicky, this isn't exact, it rounds :(