# Time since mysql timestamp PHP

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

Im looking for a simple way to calculate the time since TIMESTAMP entry on a mysql database. I would like to use php.

The timestamp is a unix format - `2013-01-15 12:46:11`

If its currently `2013-01-15 19:46:11`, what would be the most concise coding to calculate the difference the difference between the two?

Thanks for any help!
Jason

Comment: Like, `strtotime("now")-strtotime("2013-01-15 12:46:11")`?

Comment: the result is in seconds

Answer (score 4):

You want `DateInterval's` format method: `$date->diff`

```
$date = new \DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($timestamp);
$interval = $date->diff(new \DateTime('now'));
echo $interval->format('%y years, %m months, %d days, %h hours and %i minutes ago');
```

change the now to your date.

[PHP Time Since Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010016/php-time-since-function)

Comment: I'm getting a value of 48 years... (1970). Do you have to do something with the mysql timestamp?

Answer (score 3):

```
 echo ((strtotime("2013-01-15 19:46:11")-strtotime("2013-01-15 12:46:11"))/3600);
```

Comment: This worked the best for me. The other answer by Adam just defaults to 1970

Answer (score 2):

Try something like the following:

```
<?php 
    echo(time()-strtotime("2013-01-15 19:46:11"));
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some of below useful links.

https://gist.github.com/822283

[how to calculate exact hours from two timestamp in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6470411/how-to-calculate-exact-hours-from-two-timestamp-in-php)

http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2010/php-calculate-real-differences-between-two-dates-or-timestamps/

i recommend first link **(GITHUB)**